# Добавить отступы и background

Tags: javascript, html, css, adaptive-design

```js
var nav = $('.header__nav-link');
var toggler = $('.header__nav-toggle');

toggler.on('click', function() {
 nav.toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
header {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 100%), url(../img/background.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header__top {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__logo {
 color: var(--main);
 font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 45px;
}
nav {
 margin-top: 17px;
}

nav a {
 font-size: 19px;
}

nav a:not(:first-child) {
 margin-left: 4px;
}

.header__nav-toggle {
 display: none;
 font-size: 22px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 .header__nav-link {
  display: none;
 }

 .header__nav-toggle {
  display: block;
  float: right;
 }

 .header__nav-link.active {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 13px;
 }
}
```

```html
 <header>
  <div class="header__top">
  <span class="header__logo">Tesmi</span>
  <nav class="header__nav">
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-toggle">&#9776;</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Главная</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Услуги</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Навыки</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Команда</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Контакты</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 </header>
```

необходимо сделать небольшие отступы сверху и снизу между элементами меню в мобильной версии, но не получается это сделать, и хотелось бы задать полупрозрачный background, когда пункты мобильного меню раскрыты. помогите это реализовать пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, для какого элемента надо было создать background, сделала для всего меню.

```js
var nav = jQuery('.header__nav-link');
var toggler = jQuery('.header__nav-toggle');

toggler.on('click', function() {
 nav.toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
header {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 100%), url(../img/background.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header__top {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__logo {
 color: var(--main);
 font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 45px;
}
nav {
 margin-top: 17px;
}

nav a {
 font-size: 19px;
}

nav a:not(:first-child) {
 margin-left: 4px;
}

.header__nav-toggle {
 display: none;
 font-size: 22px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 .header__nav-link {
  display: none;
 }

 .header__nav-toggle {
  display: block;
  float: right;
    padding: 0 5px;
 }

 .header__nav-link.active {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
 }
  .header__nav-link.active{
    background: #00000030;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="header__top">
  <span class="header__logo">Tesmi</span>
  <nav class="header__nav">
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-toggle">&#9776;</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Главная</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Услуги</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Навыки</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Команда</a>
   <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">Контакты</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 </header>
```